# How to export to Leaflet using qgis2web with labels?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

I'm trying to use qgis2web in order to make web-ready map but I recently ran into some problems. Leaflet does not include the labels of the points I placed on the map while OpenLayers have labels. I prefer to use Leaflet over OpenLayers because it's relatively lightweight and I don't need the full suite that OpenLayer offers. The qgis2web GitHub wiki also shows a Leaflet screenshot with labels on it but I was not able to reproduce it.

I'd like to know if there is a way to make labels appear in Leaflet since having only popups for a map won't do much to people unfamiliar with the area.

[image: OpenLayers has labels by the points.]

[image: Leaflet has no labels.]

Comment: I had something similar with OpenLayers. Basically you should try to find something like:  if ("your label" !== null) {
labelText = String("your label");
}
I can't tell you roughly how it looks in leaflet generated by QGIS2Web, because I used OpenLayers. If you want more details, read this article: http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/qgis2-web-fixing-labelling-issues-in-openlayers-map/ I hope it will help you a bit. I am convinced, that with a bit of coding you can reproduce your labels successfully.

Comment: I wasn't able to make the labels appear in Leaflet using the webpage so I decided to stick with OpenLayers instead. Thanks a lot for trying to help!